# Doubt regarding Euler-Lagrange equations for a constrained system

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, euler-lagrange-equation

Assume we have a function $L(\vec q,\vec{\dot q}, t)$ (where $\vec q$ is a vector in some given number of dimensions, similarly for $\vec{\dot q}$) and we wish to find a condition for which a chosen $q(t)$ would maximize

$$ \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L \left( q(t),\dot q(t), t \right) \, {\rm d} t $$

If we vary the path by $\vec{\delta q}$ (with $\vec{\delta q}(t_1)=\vec{\delta q}(t_2)=0$  the change in the value this perturbation introduces is

$$ \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec q}\cdot \vec{\delta q}+\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec{\dot q}}\cdot \vec{\dot{\delta q}} \, {\rm d} t = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec q}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec{\dot q}} \right)\cdot \vec{{\delta q}} \, {\rm d} t $$

If $\vec q(t)$ is an extrema the integral we originally introduced, this must be 0. In any ordinary case, we could easily figure out some tricks to say that $(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec q}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec{\dot q}})_i=0$ for any index $i$, giving us the standard EL equations for a system of multiple particles.

Now, lets assume that we have a constraint on our system and the only admissible choices of $\vec q(t)$ are those such that $h(\vec q(t))=0$. Now we introduce a small perturbation $\vec{\delta q}$, and see to fit the constraints that $\nabla h_{q(t)} \cdot \vec{\delta q}=0$ We again get $\int_{t_1}^{t_2}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec q}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec{\dot q}})\cdot \vec{{\delta q}}dt=0$ for when $\vec q(t)$ is an extrema of the original integral, but this time we have less freedom with the $\vec{{\delta q(t)}}$ we can choose--this leads me to a dead end. I dont see how we can pull out the integrand in this case. If we were able to prove a similar result to the one above and say that $(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec q}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec{\dot q}})\cdot \hat{{\delta q(t)}}=0$, we could use Lagrange multipliers to rewrite this as $(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec q}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec{\dot q}})=\lambda (t) \nabla h$--the way I see this is that $(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec q}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec{\dot q}})$ will always be perpendicular to the tangent plane if we can pull the ingrained above out, which shows its parallel to $\nabla h$, giving us the existence of such a function of time to scale both values to equality. I could just be oblivious to something but with the equations trapped inside the integral, I am unsure how we get to utilize Lagrange multipliers to find a solution to such problem. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Some comments: You write vectors, but this theory is not about euclidean space with cartesian coordinates. The principle of least action is not about to maximize the action integral but to find the local equations of dynamical equilibrium around a state that varies in $\delta q, \delta \dot q$ quadatically. This is mostly a saddle with positive and negative squares. Finally, you can model any constraint by a quadratic potential in a larger space with its minimum concentrated along the submanifold of interest, solve and finally letting the extension of the potential going to 0.

Comment: @RolandF I wrote maximum instead of extrema I realize now. Also if you could elaborate on the last part, it makes sense that such a force/potential would exist to keep the particle on the constraint surface but I’m not sure exactly how to find an expression for this, it kind of makes me think of Lagrange multipliers but I’m not sure if that would work

Comment: Please consider using paragraphs

Comment: The old mathematicians were mostly analytical mechanics in the sense of Archimedes. In reality,  any mechanical constraint is a stiff elastic mechanism acting by forces otrhogonal to the submanifold against small deviations, This is in effect Lagranges idea of the free multipiers of the derivatives of the constraint equations. after his first idea, that forces and inertial reaction forces constitute an equilibrium.

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/770186/2451